# Glow around Button

Tags: cocoa, button, effect, glow

How can I draw a slight white 'glow' around a button or label in 10.5 and later? I have seen some apps do it, but I am still confused how I should do this.

Comment: can you point us to an screenshot, to know what you are referring to?

Comment: I can't get a screen shoot, but what I mean is something like Photoshop's outer glow on a button in white, that originates below the actual button, and then slowly fades out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [NSShadow](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSShadow_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You'd [create and set a shadow](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/AdvancedDrawing/AdvancedDrawing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH207-SW1) ([saving your graphics context beforehand](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/GraphicsContexts/GraphicsContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH203-SW4)), then draw the basic shape of your button, unset it (by restoring your graphics context), then continue drawing as usual.

In the case of a ready-made control like NSButton, you will need to [subclass and override its cell drawing](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ControlCell/Tasks/SubclassingNSCell.html) (and possibly make the host NSButton control itself a bit larger to accommodate the larger area needed to encompass the "glow" of the cell).

You *might* be able to avoid this with a label by setting its font shadow, but I don't think IB lets you do this, so you'd programmatically give the label an attributed string (via its -setAttributedString: method). The attributes would include the NSShadow (configured as desired) as the NSShadowAttributeName.